# Use one background image programatically for both iPhone4 and iPhone5 with NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to avoid detecting whether I'm on iPhone 4 or 5 screen size by using `NSLayoutConstraint`. This is my code:

```
UIImageView *backgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Flow-02"]];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundImage];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:backgroundImage];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[backgroundImage]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(backgroundImage)]];
```

but it doesn't work.

My Flow-02 image has a resolution of 640x1136, so I was thinking this would make it fit the screen, but it doesn't. Is there a way to do it?

EDIT: Following rmaddy's answer below I added the line that sets the image's frame like this:

```
backgroundImage.frame = self.view.bounds;
```

It does set my image correctly on the iPhone 5 simulator, but on my iPhone 4s it's still stretched sideways.

Neither the `autoresizingMask` approach, nor the  setting of `V` and `H` to the `constraintsWithVisualFormat`, suggested by Anindya Sengupta, have any effect.

Comment: "but it doesn't work" is not helpful in diagnosing your problem. What result do you see? Do you feet any warnings in the console? You've added horizontal constraints, how about vertical ones -- don't you think you should have those also?

Comment: If you wish to use Layout Constraint, I would recommend to use the interface builder (xib file). It will be much more easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be something like this:

```
UIImageView *backgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Flow-02"]];
backgroundImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
backgroundImage.frame = self.view.bounds;
backgroundImage.autoResizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[self.view addSubview:backgroundImage];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:backgroundImage];
```

Keep in mind that either approach is only a good idea of the image looks OK when scaled as needed.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy. I edited my question to reflect the improvement following your answer, and the issue that still remains.

Comment: Try also adding `backgroundImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;`. You might want a different value depending on your needs.

Comment: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill does it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the Visual Format you are setting.

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[backgroundImage]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(backgroundImage)]];
```

The above code it pinning the backgroundImage to the left and right side of the container. But the iPhone is not getting fat, right? So, lets do this additionally

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[backgroundImage]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(backgroundImage)]];
```

I just added **V:** which will tell the compiler to consider it vertically. For Horizontal it would have been **H:**
If you don't mention anything, by default it is "Horizontal" but it is a good practice to mention it always to make the code more understandable.

Comment: Thanks @Anindya, but it still doesn't seem to have any effect. I edited my question to reflect the current situation.